# magento product collection by name

Tags: magento-1.8

```
  <?php
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load();

$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   **echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';**//getting this only
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}

?>
```

i am trying to get product collection based on product name but i get only product URL.i am trying get other attributes like name.my purpose is to create a search page

Comment: did you get $_product->getId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for getting all attributes of the products

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
```

or use if you want to select few attributes

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price'))->load();
```

Comment: i think 
`$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));`
this code is not working.it displaying result for even null values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not load the collection if you still want filters to be added. This part `->load();` should be added after the `->addAttributeToFilter(` is done.